# Android Studio compiles TOO slow

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I found the latest Android Studio(0.8.12) wait TOO LONG to begin compilation. I don't know what it's doing which shown nothing in the gradle console. My project can be compiled in 1 minute in command line by `gradlew clean assembleDebug` which takes over 3 minutes in Android Studio. Anyone knows what it's doing and how to speed up?﻿

Comment: are you behind a enterprise proxy, and/or do you have any intrusive software like firewall or anti-virus.

Comment: Just to be clear: you don't need to clean your project every time. Hit "run" it's enough.

Comment: 1. No, not the network problem. In offline mode, nothing different. 2. I know clean every time is not needed. It's just for a test. Because every time it is very very slow... NO MATTER I clean or not. My project is with multiple libraries and should run proguard to shrink symbols.

Comment: So weird, I switch JDK between 1.8 and 1.6 several times. It just becomes fine. I don't know why. But it works now.

Comment: As of Gradle 2.1, there are some known problems with JDK 8 and libraries used by Gradle (e.g. Groovy). Some of these are open JDK bugs. Therefore, running Gradle with JDK 6 or 7 is a safer bet for now.

Comment: Actually, I found it waits almost 2min before compile while I change the gradle jdk to 1.7, every thing goes fine in 1.8. I'm using OS X 10.10 and gradle 1.12.